# How can I check if a wheel axle is straight?

Tags: motorcycle, wheels, alignment, axle, tips-and-tricks

I might have bent the front axle of my motorbike. How can i check if a wheel axle is straight? I'm looking for tips on how to do this in case i don't have dedicated tools available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You would want to use a [dial indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_(distance_amplifying_instrument)) and a pair of [vblocks](https://www.google.com/search?q=vblock%20precision%20tool&biw=1280&bih=663&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4obC63YLNAhUJ22MKHfsoD28Q_AUIBygC)**

In order to understand the amount of run-out you may have on your axle you will want to be able to measure the amount of run-out and you have on the axle.

You could roll it back and forth on a flat surface to get a general idea if the axle is bent but ultimately, to fully understand the issue empirically, you will need to measure the run-out.

This tool pair will allow you to do it.

[image]

The manufacturer of your bike will have the service limits of runout listed in the shop manual.